# Haskell Algebraic Data Types

Tags: haskell, types, algebraic-data-types

I have the following for an HTML font tag:

```
data Color = HexColor Int | RGBColor Int Int Int | ColorString String deriving Show
data FontAttribute = Size Int | Face String | FontColor Color deriving Show
data Font = Font [FontAttribute] deriving Show
```

I construct one like so:

```
Font [Size 23,Face "Arial",Color (RGBColor 240 23 43)]
```

My concern is that the `FontColor` data/value constructor which has type FontAttribute requires a Color type as an argument. This means that Color is a generic type attribute for any kind of tag, and a specific tag has a specific subset of attributes (in this case Font has FontAttribute, which can be Size, Face or FontColor). Is there a clearer way to express this, or is my implementation sound?

Comment: Is it intended that one can create `Font`s described by any number and combination or `FontAttribute`s? `Font [Face "Arial", Face "Impact"]` doesn't seem terribly useful...

Comment: Yes, any valid list. You can do the same in XHTML and CSS, I think what happens is implementation dependent. Usually the browser uses the last value. I was more concerned about the type heirarchy.

Comment: So, you kind of want to restrict "Color" for being used exclusively with the FontColor constructor? Is that your concern?

By the way, you don't need the parens around [FontAttribute].

Comment: No I would like Color to be generic, but I don't like the `FontColor Color` data generator, is there a clearer way to express that a FontColor is a Color as well as a FontAttribute. I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Color is just a type, not an attribute.  There is nothing in the type system to indicate that Color has any special relationship with FontAttribute.  All that happens when you define the FontAttribute data type is that it creates a constructor called FontColor which is an  ordinary function with the following type signature:

```
FontColor :: Color -> FontAttribute
```

So if you declared some new type called Link:

```
data LinkAttrubute = LinkColor Color | ...
```

Then Color could be stored in a LinkAttribute, too.  A constructor does not imply an exclusive relationship with only that data type.  All your FontAttribute data type says is that it MIGHT contain just a Color.

Haskell has no  built-in concept of attributes because it has no built-in concept of objects.  HOWEVER, you can model attributes using the Lens type from the data-lens (or fclabels)  package.  I would link you the packages, but I'm on my phone and it is difficult.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wanted. You would want Color to be generic and applicable to any data constructor.